# How to increase excel sheet column width while downloading in react js ? ,i am using a package called "export-from-json"

Tags: excel, reactjs, download

```
  downloadPropertiesInXl = async () => {
    let API_URL = "something....";
      const property = await axios.get(API_URL);
      const data = property.data;
      const fileName = "download";
      const exportType = "xls";

      exportFromJSON({ data, fileName, exportType });
    }
  };
```

is there any other packages to change column width??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Excel.js, it have many options for customization

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#columnsex